# can I edit Xcode code completion suggestions?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I love the code completion in Xcode, it saves me a lot of typing work. Also, it confirms my code is probably error-free in real time. However, to me, some code suggestions are disturbing. For example, when I type `else` after an *if*-statement, Xcode suggests this:

```
else {
    statement
}
```

I'd like to change this to just:

```
else
    statement
```

Because, I quite often just want to use one line of code there, and adding curled brackets goes much faster than removing them. The other annoying thing is the fact that using such a suggestion takes the return key, while a new line does as well. So, if I would want to use my preferred way as shown above, I would first have to press the escape key in order to stop Xcode suggesting it, and *then* press the return key. Not a real pain, but I think it's unnecessary.

There are some other code suggestions which I would like to change, but I think I have made my point already. Is there a way to change these code suggestions? I know Apple doesn't provide an easy way within Xcode itself, but I'm willing to dive into the finder for the file with suggestions and change it manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example, it would work to add a space after typing `else`. Doing that removes the brace suggestion and you can just hit enter.

Comment: Then I'm stuck with that space, haha. I'd rather use the escape key than the space bar, but I was just wondering if there was a way to change those suggestions...

Comment: @timjver Not that I know of, but I find hitting the space bar to be a little faster than going up to hit the escape key.

Comment: True, that's definitely faster. Although, I probably would end up removing all those spaces, to keep my code "clean", haha :)